# ASP.Net MVC ModelBinding - Error - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Its a bummer, I had this working now can figure out whats wrong?

HTML\ASP.NET MVC

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.BookingItems)
        {
        <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" name="BookingItems_item_Id_@item.Id"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="@item.Name" name="BookingItems_item_Name_@item.Id"/>
</div>
</div>
        }
```

ModelBinder

```
 public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {

var booking = new OnlineClientBooking();
 try
                    {
                        var items = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys
                            .Where(k => k.StartsWith("BookingItems_item_"))
                            .Select(k => int.Parse(k.Split('_')[3]))
                            .Select(i => new OnlineClientBookingItem()
                            {
 Name = (string)bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(
string.Format("BookingItems_item_Name_{0}", i)).ConvertTo(typeof(string)),
Id = (string)
 bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(string.Format("BookingItems_item_Id_{0}", i)) .ConvertTo(typeof(string)),
}).Distinct();
}
catch (Exception ea)
{
booking.BookingItems = null;
 }
}
```

I keep getting "Input string was not in a correct format." on trying to set bookingitems

Ideas?

Comment: One of entries in HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys is not X_Y_Z (where X, X and Z are integer numbers)

Comment: Sorry, dont understand?, keys are returned like BookingItems_item_Id_19634243-7db2-4622-9dce-4b5d93593bb1

Comment: That's a `guid` and you are parsing it as an `int`